# Create an instance of a class and call a method on it via variables containing the class name and method name as strings

Tags: php, class, methods, dynamic, instantiation

Problem: I need to dynamically call a class and a method of that class. The only thing I get is two strings:

```
$class = "MyClass";
$method = "myMethod";
```

How can I create an Instance of the class specified in $class and then call a method on that instance specified in $method?

Like:

```
$instance = new MyClass;
$instance->myMethod();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$instance = new $class;
$instance->$method();
```

Just like you'd expect. Obviously, though, if you're taking this as user input, you'll want to be 100% sure that you validate the class and method names against an acceptable list. If the class is *only* for public APIs, then you don't need a separate whitelist for methods, but you most definitely need to be 100% sure when you take that approach, since allowing direct user input into your program flow is very, very dangerous.

Comment: Somewhat related to this question: What if the constructor required an arbitrary amount of arguments? How could one use something similar to `call_user_func_array()` to call a constructor with an array of arguments?